How to calculate the thickness of ice formed on a lake with a known temperature gradient?
I've been working on a problem involving the formation of ice on a small lake. The surface of the lake is in thermal equilibrium with the air at $-4^{\circ} \mathrm{C}$, while the bottom remains at $4^{\circ} \mathrm{C}$. The total depth of the lake, including the ice layer, is $1.5 \, \text{m}$.
What I've Tried:

I attempted to use Fourier's law of heat conduction to estimate the heat flux from the warmer bottom to the colder surface. The equation I used is:

$$\frac{dQ}{dt} = -k \cdot A \cdot \frac{dT}{dx}$$
where $k$ is the thermal conductivity, $A$ is the area, $dT$ is the temperature difference, and $dx$ is the thickness of the ice.

I then considered the latent heat of fusion to relate the heat flux to the rate of ice formation:

$$\frac{dQ}{dt} = L \cdot \rho \cdot \frac{dV}{dt}$$
where $L$ is the latent heat of fusion, $rho$ is the density of ice, and $\frac{dV}{dt}$ is the rate of change of the ice volume.
However, I'm having trouble setting up the boundary conditions to connect these equations and accurately calculate the thickness of the ice. I'm also unsure how to integrate the temperature difference across the water and ice layers.
How can I determine the thickness of the ice layer given these conditions? Are there any additional assumptions or details I need to consider?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Is the system supposed to be at steady state, or is the ice thickness supposed to be growing?

@ChetMiller:  I don't think there's a "steady state" solution per se, given the information provided.  For any thickness of ice, there's going to be a certain thermal flux passing through it from the water to the air.  If you know how much heat is entering the lake from the ground, you could equate that with the thermal flux through the ice and solve for the thickness.  But without that information, I don't think the steady-state thickness can be determined.

Given the fixed-temperature conditions at the top and bottom, one can estimate an upper and a lower bound for the steady-state ice thickness, corresponding to zero and perfect water mixing. Convection is currently ignored in the question, but we can expect some natural convection from a temperature gradient existing in a fluid. (The lower thickness bound is zero, with the lake being well mixed enough to be above 0°C.) The time-dependent case of increasing ice thickness and a moving ice–water interface is called the Stefan problem.

If the system is at steady state. The heat flux in the ice layer must match the heat flux in the water layer(and the ice thickness is not changing).

Here is a partial answer that should get you started.
As the comments said, assuming steady state, between the 1.5m we either have ice or water, fixed "positions".  Furthermore, $\frac{dq}{dt}=0$, where $q$ is the heat density, we can derive the following equation using yours.
Heat conduction: $$j_q=-D(x)\nabla T(x),$$
where $j_q$ is the heat current density and $D(x)$ the space dependent conductivity. Assuming that it is temperature independent given some substance, it is just $D_1$ for when $T(x)<0$, ice, and $D_2$ for water, i.e. $T(x)>0$.
Energy conservation:$$\frac{dq}{dt} = -\nabla j_q$$
This gives you the temperature distribution:
$$\frac{dq}{dt}=0=\nabla(D(x)\nabla T(x))$$.
The bounday conditions are which you stated:
At $x=1.5m$ we have $T=-4$ and at $x=0$ it is 4.
Now $D$ will have a step function type behaviour which must be solved in a weak sense.
